# Custom Nav Walker check if menu child-item has child

Tags: wordpress

i have the following menu structur:

```
- alice (should have class="has-multi-level")
  - foo
    - child from foo
- alice 2 (no extra class)
  - and this bob
```

is there a way to add a class to alice if she/it has 2 level childs?

in the custom nav walker the items have only "have-child" (first level) as arg.

to clarify:
i must check on depth 0 if any child element (depth 1) has an child element (depth 2) and add a class to the depth 0 element

edit: i do it know with jQuery, but a clean solution would be nice

Answer (score -1):

Please add below code to your active themes `function.php` file

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class','add_parent_css',10,2);
function  add_parent_css($classes, $item){
     global  $dd_depth, $dd_children;
    if($dd_children && $dd_depth == 1)
    {
         $classes[] = 'depth'.$dd_depth;
         $classes[] = 'parent';
         return $classes;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no global $dd_children or $dd_depth

Comment: and if i rewrite it to my custom walker, it added the class to the wrong depth. Your filter adds the class to "foo" not to "alice" from my question

Comment: please change `dd_depth == 2` so it will add class to `alice`

Comment: no, this will add it to child from "foo"...i must go backwards not forwards

Comment: i must check on depth = 0 and than if the item has a any child with child...but dont know ho to check if any child has a child